# What could cause linking errors with global variables in header and cpp file?

Tags: c++, global-variables, linker-errors

#update:
I am letting everyone know that I found out the issue.
The file was somehow not included even though the IDE was telling me it was!? Thank you everyone!

I have a cpp file defining some global variables
and a header file declaring them(using extern).
For some reason I get linking errors when trying to use them.
I have no idea what it could be.
The header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "Camera.h"

extern int G_width;
extern int G_height;
extern Camera G_cam;

extern glm::mat4 G_model;
extern glm::mat4 G_view;
extern glm::mat4 G_proj;
```

and the cpp file:

```
#include "globals.h"

int G_width{ 800 };
int G_height{ 600 };
Camera G_cam{ glm::vec3{0,0,5} };

glm::mat4 G_model{ 1.0f };
glm::mat4 G_view{ G_cam.getView()};
glm::mat4 G_proj{ G_cam.getProj()};
```

The width and height used to work before, now they are unresolved symbols for main...

Adding more information asked in comments:
I am using visual studio 2022 and the linking errors are
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol, one for each variable that is used.

What should I do?

Comment: What are the full error messages?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You probably aren't actually compiling and linking the shown `.cpp` file. Show _exactly_ how you compile and link the program.

Comment: What is the linking error?  How are you compiling and linking the files?  The code you provided does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @G.M I don't know how to do this... I could try something simple for the 2 ints but the thing is that I imagine that in that case it would actually work. Do you think I should try that? I could also add the other variables but the think is that I don't know that it wouldn't work, I expect it would. Anyway I will try that but I expect that it's going to work

Comment: In which case you should read the comment by @user17732522 : are you sure the code you're compiling is the code you *think* you're compiling?

Comment: @G.M
Yes, I see in the solution explorer that the files are included in the project.  So I believe it is included